# Why does the indicator in ttk.Menubutton not disappear?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, styles, ttkwidgets

I wrote code with `ttk.Menubutton`, but I met a problem - the indicator does not disappear, although it was possible to remove it in `tk.Menubutton`.

### Code

`ttk.Menubutton`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

root.option_add("*Menu.borderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.activeBorderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.background", "black")


style = ttk.Style(root)


menu = tk.Menu(root)

btn_menu = ttk.Menubutton(root, text='fegvd')
btn_menu.pack()

file = tk.Menu(btn_menu, tearoff=0, foreground='white')
file.add_command(label='ГЫГ')

style.configure('TMenubutton', background='black', foreground='white', indicatoron=0, menu=file, direction='delow', state='active')

root.mainloop()
```

`tk.Menubutton`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

root.option_add("*Menu.borderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.activeBorderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.background", "black")


menu = tk.Menu(root)

btn_menu = tk.Menubutton(root, text='fegvd')
btn_menu.pack()


file = tk.Menu(btn_menu, tearoff=0, foreground='white')
file.add_command(label='ГЫГ')

btn_menu.configure(background='black', foreground='white', indicator=0, menu=file, state='active')

root.mainloop()
```

### Screenshots

`ttk.Menubutton`

[image]

`tk.Menubutton`

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indicator does not disappear because the ttk theme does not have an `indicatoron` option and `style.configure()` simply ignores the invalid options instead of raising an error.

However you probably can get rid of the indicator using `style.layout()`. The solution below does not work with the default theme on OSX, but it works for 'clam' and 'alt'. You seem to be using Windows so maybe it will also work for the Windows theme, otherwise you can change theme.

If you look at the output of `style.layout('TMenubutton')`, you will have something like

```
[('Menubutton.border',
  {'sticky': 'nswe',
   'children': [('Menubutton.focus',
     {'sticky': 'nswe',
      'children': [('Menubutton.indicator', {'side': 'right', 'sticky': ''}),
       ('Menubutton.padding',
        {'expand': '1',
         'sticky': 'we',
         'children': [('Menubutton.label',
           {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''})]})]})]})]
```

To get rid of the 'Menubutton.indicator', you can just remove it from the layout:

```
style.layout('TMenubutton', [('Menubutton.border',
  {'sticky': 'nswe',
   'children': [('Menubutton.focus',
     {'sticky': 'nswe',
      'children': [
       ('Menubutton.padding',
        {'expand': '1',
         'sticky': 'we',
         'children': [('Menubutton.label',
           {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''})]})]})]})])
```

If you need other menubuttons with an indicator, you can replace 'TMenubutton' by a custom name, e.g. 'noindicator.TMenubutton' and do `btn_menu.configure(style='noindicator.TMenubutton')` to use this layout for this particular menubutton.